# Partial fraction with complex root with multiplicity >1

Tags: partial-fractions

I have the function $\frac{x^4}{(x^2+1)^5}$ but I can't remember how to calculate the fractions residues.
I know that you can calculate the residues when the root is real and have multiplicity (r) >1 by using
$b_{k}$ = $\frac{1}{(r-k)!}$ $\frac{d^{r-k}}{ds^{r-k}}$ ($\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}(s+a)^r)$ with 1<=k<=r

Is there a similar way as above for complex roots with r>1?
For example, something like
$\beta_{k}s+\beta_{l}$ = $\frac{1}{(r-k)!}$ $\frac{d^{r-k}}{ds^{r-k}}$ ($\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}((s+a)(s-a))^r)$

Comment: That formula is usually inconvenient for computing residues. You can rather expand in power series around the relevant point.

Comment: So, suppose you want to compute residue at $x=i$. We can write $x^4/(x^2+1)^5=(x-i+i)^4(x-i)^{-5}(x-i+2i)^{-5}$. Use the binomial formula to expand in series to the term you need.

Comment: Recall that when you are dividing series you can use long division to compute successively the term of the series of the quotient.

Comment: By the way, I think the formula you posted works for any complex numbers, not only for residues at real points.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^4=((x^2+1)-1)^2=(x^2+1)^2-2(x^2+1)+1$$

should reduce your expression to friendlier looking fractions.